# Prevent ListView from cutting off first letter of ListViewItem when selected in WinRT

Tags: windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

In a `Xaml/C#` `WinRT` application, whenever a `ListViewItem` is selected, the first letter on the left gets chopped off.  How can I prevent this?

```xml
<ListView>
    <ListViewItem Content="Hello World"/>
</ListView>
```

**Unselected and Full:**

[image: Unselected and Full]

**Selected and Truncated:**

[image: Selected and Truncated]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply a margin to an item within the ListViewItem itself like below, which will stop the cut off.  Alternatively you could use a ContentTemplate as the second example.

Example 1:

```xml
<ListView>
    <ListViewItem>
        <TextBlock Text="Hello World" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
    </ListViewItem>
</ListView>
```

Example 2:

```xml
<ListView>
    <ListViewItem Content="Hello World!">
        <ListViewItem.ContentTemplate>

            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
            </DataTemplate>

        </ListViewItem.ContentTemplate>
    </ListViewItem>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Thanks, it's odd that this wouldn't do something like this out of the box

Comment: Yeah you would expect it to indent on selection automatically.  Hope it helped.

Comment: It does.  I'm actually adding the items programmatically so now I'm looking into using the `ContentTemplate` as a resource and applying it to all child items in the `ListView`

Comment: That is how I use it in my projects, gives you a nice amount of control too.

Answer (score 0):

As a follow up to Brandon Scott's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17392542/1366033), if you would rather not apply this inline, you can set this behavior as a style and then apply that style to individual list items like so

```xml
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style x:Key="ListViewItemMagin" TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Then, apply the style to your list view items

```xml
<ListView>
    <ListViewItem Content="Hello World" Style="{StaticResource ListViewItemMagin}"/>
</ListView>
```

If you want to enable this by default, you can omit the `x:Key` property on the style and it will automatically apply to any element matching the `TargetType`; like so:

```xml
<Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```